# Multipart file upload not working as expected from react native, but it's working from postman

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch, postman, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload an image using multipart upload. Here is my form data object.

```
let newPet = new FormData();
newPet.append('name', name);
newPet.append('species', species);
newPet.append('breed', breed);
newPet.append('birthday', birthday);
newPet.append('files', file);
```

Request Config:

```js
let response = await fetch(`${baseurl}/pets`, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    // Accept: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoding',
    Accept: 'application/json',
    // 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(newPet)
});
```

In the server side I am receiving an object as below:

```js
{
  _parts: [
    ['name', 'Leo'],
    ['species', 'cat'],
    ['breed', 'german'],
    ['birthday', '2-08-2018'],
    ['files', [Object]]
  ];
}
```

which is not the expected that I want.

However, from postman I am getting a file object in the req.files.

Both of the time, I am sending form data, but why it is different. How can I get the expected result that I got from postman?

Comment: It seems file is an array! Try to replace by `file[0]`

Comment: I change content type to multipart and remove Json.stringify. Just sending plain object worked for me.